# Apply UDF to multiple columns in Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe which looks like below

```
| id| age|   rbc|  bgr| dm|cad|appet| pe|ane|classification|
+---+----+------+-----+---+---+-----+---+---+--------------+
|  3|48.0|normal|117.0| no| no| poor|yes|yes|           ckd|
....
....
....
```

I have written an UDF to convert categorical `yes, no, poor, normal` into binary `0s` and `1s`

```
def stringToBinary(stringValue: String): Int = {
    stringValue match {
        case "yes" => return 1
        case "no" => return 0
        case "present" => return 1
        case "notpresent" => return 0
        case "normal" => return 1
        case "abnormal" => return 0
    }
}

val stringToBinaryUDF = udf(stringToBinary _)
```

I am applying this to the dataframe as follows

```
val newCol = stringToBinaryUDF.apply(col("pc")) //creates the new column with formatted value
val refined1 = noZeroDF.withColumn("dm", newCol) //adds the new column to original
```

**How can I pass multiple columns into the UDF so that I don't have to repeat myself for other categorical columns?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`udf` functions should not be the choice if you have `spark` functions to do the same job as `udf` functions would serialize and deserialize the column data.

Given a `dataframe` as

```
+---+----+------+-----+---+---+-----+---+---+--------------+
|id |age |rbc   |bgr  |dm |cad|appet|pe |ane|classification|
+---+----+------+-----+---+---+-----+---+---+--------------+
|3  |48.0|normal|117.0|no |no |poor |yes|yes|ckd           |
+---+----+------+-----+---+---+-----+---+---+--------------+
```

You can achieve your requirement with `when` function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def applyFunction(column : Column) = when(column === "yes" || column === "present" || column === "normal", lit(1))
  .otherwise(when(column === "no" || column === "notpresent" || column === "abnormal", lit(0)).otherwise(column))

df.withColumn("dm", applyFunction(col("dm")))
  .withColumn("cad", applyFunction(col("cad")))
  .withColumn("rbc", applyFunction(col("rbc")))
  .withColumn("pe", applyFunction(col("pe")))
  .withColumn("ane", applyFunction(col("ane")))
  .show(false)
```

The result is

```
+---+----+---+-----+---+---+-----+---+---+--------------+
|id |age |rbc|bgr  |dm |cad|appet|pe |ane|classification|
+---+----+---+-----+---+---+-----+---+---+--------------+
|3  |48.0|1  |117.0|0  |0  |poor |1  |1  |ckd           |
+---+----+---+-----+---+---+-----+---+---+--------------+
```

Now the question clearly says that you don't want to repeat the procedure for all the columns for that you can do the following

```
val columnsTomap = df.select("rbc", "cad", "rbc", "pe", "ane").columns

var tempdf = df
columnsTomap.map(column => {
  tempdf = tempdf.withColumn(column, applyFunction(col(column)))
})

tempdf.show(false)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `foldLeft` function. Having your **UDF** called `stringToBinaryUDF`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val categoricalColumns = Seq("rbc", "cad", "rbc", "pe", "ane")
val refinedDF = categoricalColumns
    .foldLeft(noZeroDF) { (accumulatorDF: DataFrame, columnName: String) =>
         accumulatorDF
            .withColumn(columnName, stringToBinaryUDF(col(columnName)))
     }
```

That will respect the immutability and functional programming.

Answer (score 1):

A **UDF** can take many parameters i.e. many columns but it should return one result i.e. one column.

In order to doing so, just add parameters to your `stringToBinary` function and it's done.

It you want it to take two columns it will look like this :

```
def stringToBinary(stringValue: String, secondValue: String): Int = {
stringValue match {
    case "yes" => return 1
    case "no" => return 0
    case "present" => return 1
    case "notpresent" => return 0
    case "normal" => return 1
    case "abnormal" => return 0
}
}
val stringToBinaryUDF = udf(stringToBinary _)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: if it takes in an array `def stringToBinary(stringValues: Array[String])` what will `stringValues[0]` represent?

Comment: it will certainly represent the first `String` in the `Array` which represent the first `Column` passed in the **UDF**. another option is to use the `*` to refer  to many argument of type `String` and pass the parameters with a comma separated notation like usual. the definition will look like that `def stringToBinary(stringValues: String*)`